# "Select a valid choice." Error using Modelform in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I dont understand why i kept getting this error:

"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
The Error Message belongs to the field "account"

Here are my model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.FloatField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Entry(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey("Account", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    expense = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    usage = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey("PaymentMethod",    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.date, self.account)
```

My view:

```
class AddExpenseView(View):
    template_name = "finance/create_booking.html"
    form_class = CreateBookingForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            "title": "StatYourLife - Neue Ausgabe",
            "create_booking_form": self.form_class(user=request.user)
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
            booking = form.save(commit=False)
            account = booking.account
            account.balance -= booking.amount
            booking.expense = True
            booking.date = timezone.now()
            user_profile.entrys += 1
            user_profile.save()
            account.save()
            booking.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("finance:index"))
        else:
            context = {
                "title": "test",
                "create_booking_form": form
            }
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

and my form:

```
class CreateBookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(CreateBookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["account"].queryset =     Account.objects.filter(owner=self.user)

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        exclude = ["expense", "date"]
```

I works fine until i try to submit this form with an account type selected.

Comment: Where is the `post` method on AddExpenseView?

Comment: Sorry, i added the post method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your post method, you have forgotten to pass the `user` to the form. Since you set the `account` field's queryset to `Account.objects.filter(owner=self.user)`, that means you have a different queryset when you display the form to when you validate the data.

Change it to:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, user=self.request.user)
```

It might be better to change the form to:

```
self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
```

Then you would get an explicit error when `user` is missing from `kwargs`.

Comment: this did the trick, i´m feeling realy dumb now ._. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this type of error while testing a modelform upon passing `account` model instance directly to `account` field. Because the modelform shows the foreign key field as select options. ie. it lists all the account objects as select options with the value `account.id` and throws error if the `account_obj not in avilable choices` (list of account ids (`[int]`)).

```
CreateBookingForm(data={'account': Account.objects.first()})
```

But here, we have to pass the account id instead of the whole account object.

```
CreateBookingForm(data={'account': Account.objects.first().id})
```